# Printing Deck of cards then shuffle and reprint

Tags: java

I am trying to accomplish the following but I am stuck trying to print the deck before shuffling it.

Create a class called DeckOfCards that stores 52 objects of the Card class. Include methods to shuffle the deck, deal a card, and report the number of cards left in the deck. The shuffle methods should assume a full deck. Create a driver class with a main method that deals each card from a shuffled deck, printing each card as it is dealt.

I can't figure out how to deal the deck before shuffled then deal a single card and report back how many cards are in the deck. please help.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DeckofCard {
    private Cards[] cards;
    int i;



    DeckofCard()
    {
        i=52;
        cards = new Cards[52];
        int x=0;
        for (int a=0; a<=3; a++)
        {
            for (int b=0; b<=12; b++)
             {
               cards[x] = new Cards(a,b);
               x++;
             }
        }
    }

    public Cards drawFromDeck()
    {


        Random generator = new Random();
        int index=0;

        do {
            index = generator.nextInt( 52 );
        } while (cards[index] == null);

        i--;
        Cards temp = cards[index];
        cards[index]= null;
        return temp;
    }


    public int getTotalCards()
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

then here is my card class

```
 public class Cards
{
    private int rank, suit;

    private static String[] suits = { "hearts", "spades", "diamonds", "clubs" };
    private static String[] ranks  = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };


    Cards(int suit, int rank)
    {
        this.rank=rank;
        this.suit=suit;
    }

    public @Override String toString()
    {
          return ranks[rank] + " of " + suits[suit];
    }

    public int getRank() {
         return rank;
    }

    public int getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

}
```

and my dealer;

```
public class Dealers {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        DeckofCard deck = new DeckofCard();
        Cards C;

        System.out.println( deck.getTotalCards() );

       while (deck.getTotalCards()!= 0 )
       {
           C = deck.drawFromDeck();
           System.out.println( C.toString() );
       }


    }

}
```

Comment: This looks a lot like homework, what have you tried so far for your `shuffle` method?

Comment: it is homework, and what I tried is wrong I think.

Comment: Random generator = new Random();
        int index=0;

        do {
            index = generator.nextInt( 52 );
        } while (cards[index] == null);

        i--;
        Cards temp = cards[index];
        cards[index]= null;
        return temp;

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get it to format.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways you could implement a shuffle method. Without doing your homework for you I can advise the following two strategies:

1. Shuffle the order of the cards

   - Traverse the list of cards from index 0 to 51
   - At each index swap the card with another random index (even itself, it is possible for a card to end up in the same spot when shuffling)
   - **Warning:** This method will work for the purposes of school, but the algorithm itself is considered *naive* as it is biased. See [this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/) article for more information.
2. Take a look at the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for extra style!
3. Don't even write your own method and instead leverage Java's [Collections:shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) method.

Comment: Do Fisher-Yates. First strategy is biased: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/

Comment: By all means, really getting to know Fisher-Yates is a great idea. But judging my the content of this question I doubt it is necessary. They should be comfortable thinking about the problem before they start optimizing.

Comment: Fisher-Yates is only negligibly more complicated (if at all), even for novices. And it's not a question of optimization. I think it's fair to say that the naive approach is simply wrong: a biased shuffle just isn't what you want. You have to consider that everyone can see this answer, not just the original poster. If you think the naive approach is worthy of discussion, you should at least include a disclaimer about the bias.